# createAsyncThunk - wait for response and do next dispatch

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I need to perform logout and then after it happened to dispatch other actions. But await doesn't wait and dispatch reset all before logout. How shoud I do ?

```
const logOut = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/logout",
  async (_, { dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      await axios.get(`/api/users/logout`);
      token.unset();
      dispatch(resetTransactions());
      dispatch(resetStats());
    } catch (err) {
      return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: As I understand async result is comming and the dispatch works erlier than asyncThunk reduser put a new data in Redux Store. I mean that after logOut "isAuthorized" state is changing to "false" but during this time all dispatches reset erlier and many functions start fetching data again (because no data exist now) but on server I logOutted - and comming "unAuthorized"

Answer (score 0):

in <try ... we have an async code and a synchronous code, so after awaiting I expected to change some states in extraReducer and then to fulfill these dispatches.
But I did not understand that extraReducer will start only aftet all code in <try .. has fulfilled. So I removed dispatch(reset ..) from <try .. and put it after LogOut function invoked.